# Getting time out in scala sttp async client

Tags: scala, asynchronous, apache-flink, sttp

Hi Everyone I need your help. Please guide on this exception.

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to ******* after 60000 ms.

Because of this exception one of the operator in flink stream becomes very slow. And cause huge backlog in kafka.

what it is the exact reason that when these timeout occurs async client comes under pressure? Does it have something to related to async backend?

We have mechanism of retry if any request fails if i reduce this timeout from 60 sec to some less val lets say 3 sec. Record will soon go to retry mechnanism will not be holding one the backend ?

I don't know what will be the downsides of it (may be huge amounts of records will going to retry) or how it will going to help in this case.

Is there any better approach for handling this?

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.{Calendar, UUID}
import io.circe._

import scala.util.Try
import org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.Executors
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.async.{AsyncFunction, ResultFuture}
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
import sttp.client._
import sttp.client.asynchttpclient.future.AsyncHttpClientFutureBackend
import sttp.model.Uri

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

class MySink(prop: Prop)
    extends AsyncFunction[Record, CallDetails] {
  @transient lazy val directExecutor: ExecutionContext =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.directExecutor())

  implicit lazy val backend = AsyncHttpClientFutureBackend()
  val uri = Uri.apply(prop.Uri())


  override def asyncInvoke(
    record: BatchRecord,
    resultFuture: ResultFuture[CallDetails]
  ): Unit = {

    try {

      val batchUUID = com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.timeBased()
      val timeStamp = getTimestampAndDate
      val token = record.sessionDetails

      val future = sendData(
        token.token.tokenString,
        record
      )

      future.onComplete {
        case Success(response) => {
          resultFuture.complete(Iterable(recordCall(response, record, batchUUID, time)))
        }
        case Failure(exception) =>
          resultFuture.complete(Iterable(recordCall(exception, record, batchUUID, time)))
      }(directExecutor)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        resultFuture.completeExceptionally(e)
    }

  }

  def sendData(
    token: String,
    record: Json,
    testUri: Option[Uri] = None
  ): Future[Response[Either[String, String]]] = {

    val jsonFormatted = record.toString()

    val dataRequest = basicRequest
      .contentType("application/json")
      .auth.bearer(token)
      .body(
        s"""$jsonFormatted"""
      )
      .post((testUri.getOrElse(uri)))

    dataRequest.send()
  }
```

Comment: You're focusing on the consequences but I would look at the root cause: why is the service you're connecting to not responding under 60s? Is it overloaded? If you reduce the timeout, you'll just get more errors and retry more quickly but likely retry more and risk to overload even more the remote service.

Comment: It happens few times in months. And we hardly received 10-50 in 1 to 5 minutes. But since there may be more other request which were not timed out because they took 50 sec, 5 sec or 45 sec (anything in between 0 - 60, 60sec is default client timeout limit). So we are thinking of reducing this timeout to 3 sec. So that it does not put pressure on the main operators by taking space in async queue and instead time consuming request can go retry kafka topic.

Comment: This can happen if decied earlier may be in 2-3 sec that this has to go in retry kafka so that few of like these does not create backpressure on main operators.

Comment: @GaëlJ Can you Please provide some guidance on it.